# best way to save in db a "is made of" kind of data - Python - Orm - Networkx

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy, networkx

I'm practicing with Orm and networkx in Python. I am wondering what is the best (or more efficient) way to save "is made of" kind of data. I guess this is also a database theory question..

"is made of" kind of data is the composition of an element, and can be a list or a graph or a single bit of data... i will use a comparison to clarify:

Say you have to make a recipe book:
I will make a *recipes* table and an *ingredients* table, and a *ingredients_of_a_recipe* table containing foreign keys to both tables.

But! A recipe can be an ingredient for other recipes (I have the recipe to make chocolate cream, and this chocolate cream is an ingredient for the cake recipe) so I have to put in the *ingredients_of_a_recipe* table a link between a recipe and another recipe.

What is the best way to do this with Orm?
I'm thinking of an *is made of* table formed this way:

- recipe_id (foreign key)
- kind_of_stuff (Enum: string - list)
- stuff (string, containing the name of the ingredient or the id of the other recipe)

is that right?

And furthermore:
In my project I'm using graphs, so the "is made of" kind of data can be a simple ingredient (like chocolate), a raw list of ingredients (another recipe: chocolate cream) or a graph of ingredients (say...different types of chocolate which involve different doses of sugar)..

**In other words: How can i make a one-to-many relationship where the "many" can be a one, a many and a one-to-may thing?**

This is difficult to expose in my own language, I hope I was at least a little clear..

thanks, and happy chocolate everyone.

Comment: I solved this simply dropping SQL :) Now I'm using a Graph database and it works good!